# Printing desired text using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML Query.

```
<div id="dvCount" style="">
  <span>Total Log Count : </span>
  <span id="spnLogCount">46</span>
</div>
```

I want to print the value `46` in Selenium WebDriver.  Please let me know the code.

I am using the following code but I am unable to get the value:

```
WebElement Text= driver.Findelement(By.cssselector(xpath).gettext();
system.out.println("total" + Text);
```

But this code is not working.  How do I properly get to the value in the "spnLogCount" tag?

Comment: Use the code but still not working No Value is  getting printed. no Error is also appearing. Let me know what should i send further.                            <div id="dvCount" style="">
<span>Total Log Count : </span>
<span id="spnLogCount">8</span>
</div>
<div>

Comment: Actual Scenario: I am inserting some values in 2-3 textbox and click on Search buttton. Based on the value, the page refreshes and takes 10-20 sec to fetch the value and it is displayed as ->total Log count: 25. I have to print this value but unable to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rajnish/Desktop/my.html");

        // way one
        // you can create your custom x path
        // one x path can be made directly using id of the span like 
        // xpath =  //span[@id='spnLogCount']
        // also not if you are not sure of the tag name then you can also use * in xpath like below
        String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
        System.out.println("Total Log Count :  " + myText);

        // way two
        // you can directly use id 
        myText = driver.findElement(By.id("spnLogCount")).getText();
        System.out.println("Total Log Count :  " + myText);

        // way three
        // if you are using css selector then for id you can use #
        myText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#spnLogCount")).getText();
        System.out.println("Total Log Count :  " + myText);

    }
```

UPDATE

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-3")).click();
             driver.findElement(By.linkText("Info Log")).click();

             driver.findElement(By.id("txtMessage")).sendKeys("Push Success");

             driver.findElement(By.id("txtMachineName")).sendKeys("AC204");

             driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys("91");

             driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();

            // use it just before the sendkeys code like this 
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")));
            String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dvCount']/span[2]")).getText();
            System.out.println(text);
Hope this helps
```

Comment: Actual Scenario: I am inserting some values in 2-3 textbox and click on Search buttton. Based on the value, the page refreshes and takes 10-20 sec to fetch the value and it is displayed as ->total Log count: 25. I have to print this value but unable to do so.

Comment: ok have you used implicit wait on webdriver instance like as below driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); it will force selenium to wait for a weblement to wait a max of 20 seconds then only it will throw an error also use the above code just below where you are creating browser instance like firefox/chrome or sth else

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-3")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Info Log")).click();
     
     driver.findElement(By.id("txtMessage")).sendKeys("Push Success");
     
     driver.findElement(By.id("txtMachineName")).sendKeys("AC204");
     
     driver.findElement(By.id("txtPortal")).sendKeys("91");
     
     driver.findElement(By.id("btnSearch")).click();
     
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     
      String myText = driver.findElement(By.id("spnLogCount")).getText();
         System.out.println("Total Log Count :  " + myText);

Comment: but still not getting the result

Comment: if possible can you provide me the actual url on which you are working also if you are not getting any result then what is the error message in your console

Comment: Not getting any error in the console. the code is running successfully but the result is not coming. it is printing only total Log count : . The value is not getting printed. its a intranet web application . the Url wont work. Should i share the view source of that page or the screenshot of the same page.

Comment: plz share screenshot, also plz share complete source code so that i can create a dummy html of it at my side

Comment: pls share your skype id if possible . or else i will share u the view source here

Comment: i have shared the HTML code on your respective gmail id(raajrajnish@gmail.com).Also the screenshot

Comment: Hey after going through your source code i realized that span tag with id spnLogCount comes after some time i.e it is getting generated at runtime so i have update my answer hope this will help you thanks

Comment: thanks for your response. I have executed the code and it worked and i have got the result .

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/span"));
String text = textElement.getText();
System.out.println("Value: " + text);
```

Comment: Use the code but still not working .Value:   is only getting printed. no Error is also appearing. Let me know what should i send further.                            <div id="dvCount" style="">
<span>Total Log Count : </span>
<span id="spnLogCount">8</span>
</div>
<div>

Answer (score 0):

```
String text=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='spnLogCount']")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Use the code but still not working No Value is  getting printed. no Error is also appearing. Let me know what should i send further.                            <div id="dvCount" style="">
<span>Total Log Count : </span>
<span id="spnLogCount">8</span>
</div>
<div>

Comment: Actual Scenario: I am inserting some values in 2-3 textbox and click on Search buttton. Based on the value, the page refreshes and takes 10-20 sec to fetch the value and it is displayed as ->total Log count: 25. I have to print this value but unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I updated you code, please use below it will work.

```
String Text= driver.findElement(By.cssselector("#spnLogCount")).gettext();
System.out.println("total" + Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a JUnit test (and using [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) to handle the gecko driver):

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.FirefoxDriverManager;

public class FirefoxTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        FirefoxDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080"); // Here your URL
        WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("spnLogCount"));
        System.out.println(webElement.getText());
    }

}
```